# I cannot install ubuntu 14.04 lts on my PC!

Tags: 14.04, lts

I have windows 7 on my PC and i really wanted to install ubuntu 14.04 on my Desktop so i downloaded it from the official ubuntu website ( www.ubuntu.com ) and I have 2 problems:

---

1) The file is only 300 mb large
2) when i open the iso image it opens roxio disk burner and tells me to burn the image into a disk

---

What i did is that the I got it from another computer, put it on a pendrive  and used the file to install ubuntu on the other computer as the other one does not have internet. So, please help me on this one. I am trying to install ubuntu on my friend's PC and this is happening. THANK YOU GUYS SO MUCH! YOU'R ALL AWESOME :)

Comment: Did you download iso from [this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)?

Comment: @Jatttt : If file in only 300MB then it seems corrupt/not-downloaded-completely because it is of 964MB see: http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: Broken download maybe? If you download from the terminal using   `wget -c URL-of-the-download` it will resume the download if it is paused or otherwise interrupted until the download is completed.

Comment: download the image using a torrent, its more relaible..

Comment: @Jatttt : And for creating Usb-Stick follow : http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to make your usb pendrive bootable for that please download and install USB universal Installer 1.9.5.2.[Download From here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

In this websites some steps are given to make pendrive bootable and install through it

1. You can use any DVD to install it.You need to copy iso file in your DVD and [burn it](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) and when you will restart your pc.Open recovery mode option by pressing F12 continuously in and then select DVD option to go further and then you can see ubuntu installations steps on your screen same as USB Pendrive
2. You can Re download it as it seems the file may be corrupted as you mentioned file size